# Numpy lists of lists that doesn't flatten

Tags: python, numpy

**PROBLEM**

I want to make an empty list of lists and then append it with lists (each containing 3 elements).

```
rows = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'b', 'a'], ..., ['a', 'c', 'b']]
values = np.array([]) 
for row in rows:
    values = np.append(values, row)
```

The problem is that by default the values are being flattened.

**SOLUTION ATTEMPTS**

I've tried using 'empty' and 'ndarray' instead of an array. Moreover, I've tried setting the shape or dtype -- but values are always flattened.

Comment: Please also share a sample of `rows`. What is it's shape?

Comment: If you want a list of lists, don't use NumPy.

Comment: Why do you want to use numpy for this?

Comment: you can use a list comprehension, `[item for each_row in rows for item in each_row]`

Comment: Did you  read the `np.append` docs?  It's quite clear that without the `axis` parameter it flattens the arguments.  But why the iteration?  Why not `np.array(rows)`, or `np.vstack(rows) ` or `np.stack(rows)`?

Comment: `np.array([]) `is not an "empty" list of arrays; it's only superficially like a `[]` list.  Take some time to learn to use `np.concatenate`, paying attention to inputs and dimensions.  `np.stack` and `np.vstack` are also useful.  `np.append` is useless trap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a numpy array based on your data, make a numpy array:

```
values = np.array(rows)
```

That's pretty much the point of the constructor.